# Order a Django QuerySet by a specific ManyToMany Object

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter

I have two classes - Arzt and Fachbereich - related by a ManyToMany relationship through ArztFachbereich.

```
class Fachbereich(FachbereichUndArztFachbereiche):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)

class Arzt(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    fachbereich = models.ManyToManyField(Fachbereich, through="ArztFachbereich")

class ArztFachbereich(FachbereichUndArztFachbereiche):
    arzt = models.ForeignKey(Arzt)
    fachbereich = models.ForeignKey(Fachbereich)
    note = models.FloatField()
```

I know how I can get the result ordered by the minimum note for Arzt.

```
Arzt.objects.annotate(best_note=Min("arztfachbereich__note")).order_by("best_note")
```

But next I first filter Arzt by a Fachbereich-ID (fb_id). And now I do not need the minimum note or something aggregated, but the note for this specific ArztFachbereich.

To clarify what I am talking about:
something like this... but I have no clue how to do it in django.

```
aerzte = Arzt.objects.filter(fachbereich=fb_id)
aerzte.order_by("arztfachbereich__note"
                WHERE arztfachbereich__fachbereich == 
                Fachbereich.objects.get(id=fb_id))
```

Or another way I thought about:

```
aerzte = Arzt.objects.filter(fachbereich=fb_id)
aerzte.annotate(specific=ArztFachbereich.objects.get(arzt=self, fachbereich__id=fb_id)
aerzte.order_by("specific")
```

But I obviously can't access arzt wit that self statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
Arzt.objects.filter(arztfachbereich__fachbereich_id=fb_id)
            .order_by("arztfachbereich__note")
```

Any queries about this relationship are going to operate on the `ArztFachbereich` table (possibly `JOIN`ed to the `Arzt` and `Fachbereich` tables, depending on the query). Here, the `filter()` is going to correspond to a SQL `WHERE` clause that limits the rows to a specific value of `fachbereich_id`, and the `order_by` then orders the remaining rows by the `note` value.

I think your confusion comes from the fact that we're querying on the `Artz` model. Does this make more sense: `ArztFachbereich.objects.filter(fachbereich_id=fb_id).order_by("note")`? The two statement are essentially equivalent, but filtering on `Artz` lets you end up with `Artz` objects rather than `ArztFachbereich` objects.

(If it's not the case that `artz` and `fachbereich` are `unique_together`, you will also need to put `distinct()` at the end of the query to make sure you don't end up with duplicate `Artz` instances in your final query set.)

Comment: Seems to work... but I don't understand why^^ I am filtering Arzt but can access arztfachbereich__note of a specific ArztFachbereich Objects...?